# How to get linux to stop asking "There are # rows, list them anyway? [n/y]" for auto-completing

Tags: linux, command-line, autocomplete, tcsh

How do I get tcsh to stop asking if I want to list files in a directory that may have a lot of auto-completes?

For example, if I do: `xemacs ../"TAB"` to get the list of files it asks:

> There are 371 rows, list them anyway? [n/y]

I don't want it to ask this, just list them.. it's getting tiresome.

(Or how to at least set the tolerance to a higher number of auto-completes before it asks)

Thanks.

Comment: This isn't being done by linux (which is a kernel), it's being done by bash

Comment: @Daenyth The OP specifies `tcsh` (which is a little more obvious in the edit). But, yeah.

Answer (score 2):

In your $HOME/.cshrc, you want to add

```
set listmax = 10000
set listmaxrows = 1000
```

From the manpage

> listmax and listmaxrows can be set to limit
>      the number of items and rows  (respectively)  that  are  listed  without  asking
>      first.

You can adjust the numbers to suit your individual tastes.

Answer (score 1):

In your inputrc file, set the following variable:

```
set completion-query-items xxxxx
```

where xxxxx is the number of items at which you will be asked to display or not.

Comment: This works for bash, but not tcsh